# How to add constructor in App.js file in react-native version 3+

Tags: constructor, react-native

I am new to react-native development. I want to add constructor in app.js file and that is using the bottom tab navigator component. Due to App container I am stuck where to add constructor and how it called.

Query:-
- How to add constructor and method inside this class.

My code is as below (**App.js**) file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { f, auth, database, storage } from './config/config.js';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import feed from './app/screens/feed.js';
import upload from './app/screens/upload.js';
import profile from './app/screens/profile.js';

const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator (
  {
     Feed: { screen: feed },
     Upload: { screen: upload },
     Profile: { screen: profile }
  }
  );

const App = createAppContainer(MainStack);

export default App;
```

If anyone have idea about this. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { f, auth, database, storage } from './config/config.js';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import feed from './app/screens/feed.js';
import upload from './app/screens/upload.js';
import profile from './app/screens/profile.js';

const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator (
{
  Feed: { screen: feed },
  Upload: { screen: upload },
  Profile: { screen: profile }
}); 

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
      return <AppContainer/>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kivul for answer, But I want to merge the both things. I mean I want to use or exaport the appContainer also in same file. I am not getting at all...:(

Comment: getting error "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component"

Comment: Having some issue in another file. Solved now. Thanks your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

We can use tab as home screen and another screen as stack.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { f, auth, database, storage } from './config/config.js';
import feed from './app/screens/feed.js';
import upload from './app/screens/upload.js';
import profile from './app/screens/profile.js';
import userProfile from './app/screens/userProfile.js';
import comments from './app/screens/comments.js';

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator (
    {
      Feed: { screen: feed },
      Upload: { screen: upload },
      Profile: { screen: profile }
    }
  );

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: { screen: TabStack },
      User: { screen: userProfile },
      Comments: { screen: comments }
    },
    {
      initalRouteName: 'Home',
      mode: 'modal',
      headerMode: 'none',
    }
  )
const AppContainer  = createAppContainer(MainStack);


export default class App extends React.Component {

  login = async() => {
    //Force user to login
    try{
      let user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword('xyz@test.com', 'XXXXX');
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.login();
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <AppContainer />
  );
}
}
```

I hope this may help to others. Thanks!